# How to get HTTP server to run?

Tags: python, server, cgi

I am trying to setup a Python server so that I can build a website to run my Python scripts. I understand that I need to set up a server with cgi, but I am not really a networking expert, nor too strong in Python programming.

Basically, I am looking to setup a website that has ability to click a button and in turn it runs a python script that I have.

I am running `python -m http.server 8000` (or `python -m http.server --cgi 8000`) command and I am assuming that this should be my local server. I try opening http://127.0.0.1:8000/, but I get a message saying This site can't be reached.

Now I do not have any website there or anything like that so I'm not sure if this is ok or not. Does anyone have suggestions as to what I should do and how I get this up and running?  Do you think this may have something to do with my work firewall?

Let's say I have a simple website built like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button>Click here to run script!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have a script called `testrun.py`.

Thank you very much for your help!

**I am running on Python3, Windows 7.**

Comment: What was displayed on the command prompt after running that command?

Comment: `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...`

Comment: Tried opening [http://localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000)?

Comment: Wow, that just opened my directory of files. Is that what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Yes. That's what supposed to happen.

Comment: Now, how do I set up my script to operate through this? How do I get this server up an running by solely running a python file?

Comment: The normal way, write index.html, cgi scripts and use --cgi option.

Comment: Any chance you can link me in the right direction? or show me an example? I am quite new to this.

Comment: Something like [this](https://tasdikrahman.me/2015/10/20/Running-CGI-Scripts-with-CGIHTTPServer/)? Here the guy is using python2 instead of python3. So to run don't use the command he/she used on the blog. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Perfect! Will look into this now. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

By typing `python -m http.server 8000` you started a server but, depending on your settings, it is not always running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/

For a more general approach visit http://localhost:8000